# Material UI disable Menu transition

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to disable transition from Material UI Menu component. I've literally tried everything I could imagine but transition stays.. Any ideas how to do that? Google doesn't really help at this time.

Comment: It's right there on the API documentation for this component: `transitionDuration={0}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `transitionDuration` to 0. https://material-ui.com/api/menu/

```js
<Menu
  elevation={0}
  getContentAnchorEl={null}
  transitionDuration={0}
  anchorOrigin={{
    vertical: 'bottom',
    horizontal: 'center',
  }}
  transformOrigin={{
    vertical: 'top',
    horizontal: 'center',
  }}
  {...props}
/>
```

Comment: I do wonder if this is the _best_ way to do this, though. Seems like there should be a way to just turn it off, rather than short-circuting it with a 0s duration?